# How to make android phone ring?

Tags: android

I would like to make a android phone ring through code. 
For example a app installed and the use recieves a call a app listens for this. If a certain number calls then a specific ringtone plays. How do i go about make  code to make a android phone ring?

Comment: Unlike iphones, android phones can actually make and receive phone calls...

Comment: Provided the battery isn't dead :-)

Comment: isn't this already a feature..  set the ringtone for a specific caller id?

Comment: `Phone p = new Phone(); p.ringPhone();` two lines of code sheesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all i thought it was a good question but apparently people dont understand what you are asking. I think that you want to like call the phone you are calling from or somthing like that, i dont know it is possible but heres the tutorial on phone calls, from the official android website:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/network/sip.html

Comment: For example a sms intent is received and a sms equals a certain parameter in a app. if this certain app is installed then android phone vibrates or rings or uses a notification. to alert the user. almost like an alarm or something.

Answer (score 2):

A ring is simply a sound file played through the speaker. Read up on how to configure your mediaplayer object to play your required sound through the external speaker.

Comment: Given the similarity in user name, I just had to answer!

Comment: Lol i know i thought you had  my name for a second.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the functionality of android anyway! I am positive that this is not possible to do with an android app without modifying the os. Apps cannot initiate incoming calls for security reasons.